# Objects not moving with transition on postion : fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i was kind of building a fixed navbar by the right side of my design with position fixed , and i used jquery to toggle class one with display : none, and the other with display: block.

when code scrolls past say 300px height the sidebar shows if not it hides.

but when it scroll past say 300px high the side bar shows automatically with no transition effect, i have already generated a transition style for my design but does not seem to work, please i need help on this.

here is my code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 // browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link is shown
 var offset = 300,
  //browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link opacity is reduced
  offset_opacity = 1200,
  //duration of the top scrolling animation (in ms)
  scroll_top_duration = 700,
  //grab the "back to top" link
  $back_to_top = $('.even-more-sq-rt');

 //hide or show the "back to top" link
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $back_to_top.addClass('even-more-post-visible') : $back_to_top.removeClass('even-more-post-visible');

 });


});
```

```css
   
.even-more-sq-rt {
    width: 300px !important;
    max-height: 350px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    background: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    padding:  20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-right: 0px;
}
        
        
.even-more-sq-rt-postmeta h3 {
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
        
        
.even-more-sq-rt-thumb.img-responsive {
    height: 145px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.even-more-sq-rt {
    text-align: center;
}

.close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #333;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 3px 11px;
    color: #fff;
}

.even-more-sq-rt h3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
        
.even-more-sq-rt {
    display: none;
    transition: all 12s ease-in 5s;
}

.even-more-post-visible {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>

<div class="even-more-sq-rt">
           <h3>Trending Now</h3>
                    <button class="close-btn">X</button>
                <div class="even-more-sq-rt-inner clearfix">
                    
                    <div class="even-more-sq-rt-thumb img-responsive">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/259x145">
                    </div>
                    <div class="even-more-sq-rt-postmeta">
                        <h3><a href="#"> when there is no more words to say : silence is golden</a></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

here is the transition i would love to add :

```
-webkit-transition: right 500ms cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
-moz-transition: right 500ms cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
-o-transition: right 500ms cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
transition: right 500ms cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
-moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
-o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
```

Answer (score 0):

Was it something like this you where looking for, the only thing I did was adding a css3 animation and adding it to the even-more-post-visible style.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 // browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link is shown
 var offset = 300,
  //browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link opacity is reduced
  offset_opacity = 1200,
  //duration of the top scrolling animation (in ms)
  scroll_top_duration = 700,
  //grab the "back to top" link
  $back_to_top = $('.even-more-sq-rt');

 //hide or show the "back to top" link
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $back_to_top.addClass('even-more-post-visible') : $back_to_top.removeClass('even-more-post-visible');

 });


});
```

```css
.even-more-sq-rt {
    width: 300px !important;
    max-height: 350px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    background: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    padding:  20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-right: 0px;
}
        
        
.even-more-sq-rt-postmeta h3 {
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
        
        
.even-more-sq-rt-thumb.img-responsive {
    height: 145px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.even-more-sq-rt {
    text-align: center;
}

.close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #333;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 3px 11px;
    color: #fff;
}

.even-more-sq-rt h3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
        
.even-more-sq-rt {
    display: none;
    transition: all 12s ease-in 5s;
}

.even-more-post-visible {
    display: block;
    animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>
<h3> some space </h3>

<div class="even-more-sq-rt">
           <h3>Trending Now</h3>
                    <button class="close-btn">X</button>
                <div class="even-more-sq-rt-inner clearfix">
                    
                    <div class="even-more-sq-rt-thumb img-responsive">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/259x145">
                    </div>
                    <div class="even-more-sq-rt-postmeta">
                        <h3><a href="#"> when there is no more words to say : silence is golden</a></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: hello @Linushg111 , thank you , but i am really not good with key frame, is there any way i can implement this with the above transition i generated ?